# Assign 3 values to make one record becomes three records

Tags: sas

I want to make a simple dataset as left, to become a dataset at the right.
There are three values for V1, 1,2,3. And I want to assign it to each of the id.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem. Do this

```
data have;
input id;
datalines;
1
2
;

data want;
   set have;
   do _N_ = 1 to 3;
      v1 = put(_N_, z2. -l);
      output;
   end;
run;
```

Comment: Note there is no need for the `-L` modifier on the format specification. There are no leading spaces generated by the Z format to be removed.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not know I can have three parameters in the PUT() function. And I always use $2. instead of z2., maybe this caused the difference?

Comment: The `-L` is part of the format specification, not a separate parameter to the function.  The $2 format is for character data.  The regular 2. format (or one of its alias like F2.) is for numeric data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data have;
input id;
datalines;
1
2
;

data want;
   set have;
   do v1 = 1 to 3;
      output;
   end;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: What if I want the V1 to be "00", "01", "02" instead?

Comment: Do you want V1 to be character? Just have it print the numbers with exactly two digits that include a leading zero on values less than 10?